# Use limsup and liminf to define f is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am confused about the proof Lebesgue's Theorem for the Differentiability of Monotone Functions,There is a statement:the set of points for which f is not differentiable on (a,b) is
S={$ x \in (a,b): \overline{D}f(x)= \infty$}$\cup$ {$x\in(a,b):\infty \gt \overline{D}f(x)>\underline{D}f(x)$} 
My question 1:Does they forget the case where {$ x \in (a,b): \overline{D}f(x)= -\infty$} 
[Here is the detailed proof.](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-theorem-for-the-differentiability-of-monotone-fun)

Answer (score 1):

They forgot the case when $\underline{D}f(x)=-\infty$. However, the proof that the measure of that set is zero should go similarly to the case of $\overline{D}f(x)=\infty$ which they address.

Comment: *the proof that the measure of that set is zero should go similarly to the case of* $\overline{D}f(x)=\infty$ --- Alternatively, the $\underline{D}=-\infty$ case follows by applying the $\overline{D}=\infty$ case to $-f(x).$

Comment: $E \cap [c_k, d_k] \subseteq \{ x \in [c_k, d_k] : \overline{D} f(x) \geq |\alpha| \}$,I dont understand the relation bwteen the two sets,why is it $\lvert {\alpha} \rlert}$.Could you help me?

Comment: \lvert {\alpha} \rlert is $|\alpha|$